# Find a real matrix with known eigenvalues and one known eigenvector

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix $D=diag(3+i,3-i,2,5)$, and T be a non-singular $4\times4$ matrix with the columns
$$T_1=\begin{pmatrix} 7+4i\\8-i\\1+3i\\2+5i \end{pmatrix},\ T_2=\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4 \end{pmatrix},\ T_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\b_1\\b_2 \end{pmatrix},\ T_4=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\b_3\\b_4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Let $A$ be a $4\times4$ matrix such that $T^{-1}AT=D$.

Give necessary and sufficient conditions on $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\in\mathbb{C}$ under which $A$ is real.
$$$$
What I did:

$T_2$ must be the conjugate of $T_1$, therefore: $\ T_2=\begin{pmatrix} 7-4i\\8+i\\1-3i\\2-5i \end{pmatrix}$.

Also $T_3,T_4$ must be linearly independent of each other.

Hints on how to find $b_i$ will be most appreciated.

Edit: I tried solving it by calculating:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d\\e & f & g & h\\i & j & k & l\\m &n &o &p \end{pmatrix}\\A\begin{pmatrix} 7+4i\\8-i\\1+3i\\2+5i \end{pmatrix}=(3+i)\begin{pmatrix} 7+4i\\8-i\\1+3i\\2+5i \end{pmatrix}\\A\begin{pmatrix} 7-4i\\8+i\\1-3i\\2-5i \end{pmatrix}=(3-i)\begin{pmatrix} 7-4i\\8+i\\1-3i\\2-5i \end{pmatrix}\\A\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\b_1\\b_2 \end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\b_1\\b_2 \end{pmatrix}\\A\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\b_3\\b_4 \end{pmatrix}=5\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\b_3\\b_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
But it seemed too complex.

Edit (2):
Looking at the equations I mentioned in the former edit, if we set $c=d=g=h=l=o=0,\ k=2,\ p=5$, and add the second equation to the third, we get much simpler equations, as one of the equations will have only the real part and the other only the imaginary. From there it's easy to arrive at an answer.

This method gives:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4\frac{1}{3} & -1\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0\\
1\frac{2}{3} & 1\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{10}{13} & -\frac{12}{13} & 2 & 0\\
-1\frac{34}{39} & \frac{20}{39} & 0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$

This gives a real matrix $A$, but I still need to find the conditions on $b_i$.

Comment: Hint: You know $T_{1}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $3+i$

Comment: @Fightclub1995 do you suggest I retry what I mentioned in the edit, or look for another angle to make use of your hint?

Comment: Try coming at it from the other direction: you know that $A=TDT^{-1}$. You already have the first two columns of $T$ and it’s a block matrix, so inverting it isn’t terribly tedious. This should give you some constraints on the $b$’s.

Comment: If you write $4\tfrac{1}{3}$ and mean $4+\tfrac{1}{3}$ instead of $4 \times  \tfrac{1}{3}$ be proud: you will soon belong to an endangered species: the people who keep middle age notations ...

Comment: @JeanMarie what you are saying doesn't make sense. If someone writes $4\frac{1}{3}$ and means $4\cdot \frac{1}{3}$ why don't you just write $\frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: @FightClub1995 "Why don't you just write", but it's not me that uses these notations... Anyhow, as you have maybe noticed, it was with a touch of humor...